# How to manually turn off hover state on a drag and drop element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop

Hello Im trying to use tooltip on a dragable element before the real drag event fires.
Works fine until i drop the element to a new container.
The old tooltip fires up again but this time to the next element on the list, eventhough the cursor is nowhere near.

Im guessing hover state wont get fired off on a drag and drop "drag" event.

[image: 1) See tooltip, 2) Drag element away , binded "hidden" class onto to element 3) Old tooltip opens up on a new element, cursor is no where near.]

CSS

```
.plutof-tooltip-hover {
  position: relative;
  /*display: inline;*/
}

.plutof-tooltip { /* hide and position tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: initial;
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  z-index: 110;
  /*width: auto;*/
  /*
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  */
}

.plutof-tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 12%;
  /*margin-left: -8px;*/
  /*margin-bottom: -8px;*/
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.plutof-tooltip-hover:hover .plutof-tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline;
  transition-delay: 0.66s;
}
```

Handlebars template also the area of dragable items

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default plutof-panel">
                                    <div class="panel-body projectPanel">

                                    {{#each sampleForm in view.samplingarea_form}}
                                        {{#draggable-item content=sampleForm.id dragStarted=view.dragStart}}

                                            <div class="plutof-tooltip-hover">
                                                     <span class="label label-info formItems">{{sampleForm.measurement.name}} </span>
                                                <div>
                                                        <span {{bind-attr class=":plutof-tooltip view.dragStart:hidden"}}>

                                                                <p>{{sampleForm.measurement.description}}</p>
                                                        </span>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>

                                        {{/draggable-item}}
                                    {{/each}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
Dragable dropzone..

                        {{#draggable-dropzone itemDropped="formAdded" targetO=view dragStarted=view.dragStart}}
                             {{#each measurementform in view.measurementforms}}
                                     {{measurementform}}
                                {{/each}}
                        {{/draggable-dropzone}}
```

Drag start

```
dragStart: function(event) {
        this.set('dragStarted', true);
        return event.dataTransfer.setData('text/data', Ember.get(this, 'content'));
    }
```

Drop zone

```
dragLeave: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.set('dragClass', 'deactivated');
    },
    dragOver: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.set('dragClass', 'activated');
    },
    drop: function(event) {
        this.set('dragStarted', false);
        var targetIsView = this.get('targetO'); 
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/data');
        if(Ember.isNone(targetIsView)) {
            this.sendAction('itemDropped', data); 
        } else {
            var targetOfn = this.get('itemDropped');
            this.get('targetO').send(targetOfn, data);
        }
        this.set('dragClass', 'deactivated');    
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some js code of the drag/drop event handlers.

Comment: Try unbinding mouseenter and mouseleave on drag and bind again on the drop event.

Comment: @rashid added some code if it helps. Could you provide a code example of unbinding

Comment: @AndreaLigios There aint really no generated code. The dom node gets deleted

Comment: My bad. Then make it work directly in angular in the fiddle

Comment: @AndreaLigios This has taken me quite a while do develop, cant just put it inside a fiddle and make it work. Copying the DOM is quite hard as well since each dom node that has been backed up by a value from model gets an Ember view genereated around , like this. http://dpaste.com/32FV9CK. But im telling you the dom node that i drag off. gets removed from the right side container. Then in in a little while a new tooltip appears. as if the cursors x;y has not been changed. And yes it re-appears , not just stays there...